# Qaterial widgets in PySide2

Tags: python, qml, pyside2

Recently I came across this useful repository containing material widgets for qml (https://github.com/OlivierLDff/Qaterial). I'm wondering if there is a way to use these widgets with PySide2-QML.

As far as I've searched, there is no resource that instructs how to use these widgets with PySide2 and QML.